# How to set min x, min y, max y, and min y MPAndroidChart to fit chart in chart window

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

From

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

I tried fitScreen(), but it had no effect.

How do I set min x, min y, max y, and min y MPAndroidChart to fit chart in chart window ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already added values to the chart?
If not, call `setYRange(...)` to set the y-min and y-max. For setting the x-values, simply create a new data object (e.g. `LineData`) and set your x-values for it:
(this example will create x-min: 0 and x-max: 30)

```
private void addEmptyData() {
   // create 30 x-vals
   String[] xVals = new String[30];

   for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
       xVals[i] = "" + i;

   // create a chartdata object that contains only the x-axis labels (no entries or datasets)
   LineData data = new LineData(xVals);
   mChart.setData(data);
   mChart.invalidate();
}
```

This will create an empty chart with your desired bounds.

For dynamically adding entries, refer this: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/DynamicalAddingActivity.java